# System backup to restore even offline

Tags: backup

My goal is to backup my current system state with all its packages in such a way that I could get everything back & running even without an internet connection. So ideally I would perform these backups **daily.**

At the same time I don't want to create full system images from scratch because that would take a lot of time, so I want to only sync the modified data. Is it as simple as copying certain folders on root and then after a fresh install overwriting the fresh install's folders with the backup ones? Would this overwriting work while the system is running?

If not, is there a full system image backup software that only syncs the modified data instead of doing each backup image from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called Déja Dup integrated in Ubuntu. You can find it in applications (Ubuntu Dash) under utilities with the name Backups.
For information also see [Link](https://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/).

Answer (score 0):

Consider `timeshift`. It's in the default repos in the lastest Ubuntu versions, available via [PPA](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/wiki/Installation) in, for example, 18.04 LTS.

Highly configurable, here's the screen for one of my systems that does a daily backup and keeps 1 week of said backups around.

[image]

It does *not* back up user data, just the system. For that use `deja dup` the default backup utility.

Comment: By user data you mean `/home` or is there user data in `/root` as well?